# Finding Number of Zeros in the First Quadrant of a Complex Polymomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I am trying to determine the number of roots of $p(z) = z^6 + 4z^4 + z^3 + 2z^2 + z + 5$ in the first quadrant. I I understand that one does this by finding the change in argument of $p(z)$ over the boundary of the quarter disc of radius $R$ (for large $R$) centered at the origin. I found the change over the real axis and the circular arc, but I don't understand how to find the change over the imaginary axis from $iR$ to $0$.I consulted my book but found the discussion very confusing and not very rigorous. I cou use some help.

Note that $p(it) = -t^6 + 4t^4 - 2t^2 + 5 + i(-t^3 + t)$, where $0 \le t \le R$. Because $-t^6$ dominates the real part, and $-t^3$ dominates the imaginary part, we see that $p(iR)$ lies in the third quadrant.
Not exactly sure where in the 3rd quadrant it is, so I can't say exactly what $\arg p(iR)$ is, but whatever I guess. Then from my understanding I am suppose to find the nonnegative zeros of the real and imaginary part and track where it crosses the real and imaginary axis, and then look at it's final position. But this how can I calculate the argument change if I don't know exactly where these points are?
$p(0) = 5$, so it ends up in the first quadrant. According to a solution I found, the change in argument over the imaginary axis is $\cong \pi$, but I don't see it for some reason. I don't like these estimates.

Answer (score 1):

There is not too much more to say, and what little it takes is basically Calculus I curve-sketching analysis. Observe that when $t>1$, $p(it)$ is in the lower half-plane and, as $t\to\infty$, $\arg(p(it))\to -\pi$, since the slope for large $t$ is approaching $0$. On the interval $[0,1]$, $p(it)$ starts and ends on the positive real axis, staying in the first quadrant between. Thus, $\Delta\arg_{[0,i]} p(z)=0$. Since $p(z)$ is in the second and third quadrants for $t>1$, we conclude that $|\arg(p(it)) - \arg(p(i))|<\pi$ for all $t>1$. Thus $\Delta_{[0,R]}\arg f(it)$ approaches $-\pi$ as $R\to\infty$. Now just turn everything upside-down.